# Closing modal when clicking window outside container - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following layout which I'm practicing with, but can't get my head round what to target:

HTML

```
<button id="opencontact" type="button" name="button">
  <i class="far fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
</button>

<section id="contact-section">
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-content">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <label for="">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Message</label>
      <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
      <button type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#opencontact {
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

#contact-section {
  height: 60%;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

#contact-section.show {
  display: flex;
}

.contact-container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-content {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And a basic jQuery script to open the contact-section on click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#opencontact").click(function() {
    $("#contact-section").toggleClass("show");
  });

</script>
```

What script would I add to that to make the modal close on clicking the window outside the contact section? All solutions I've found online don't work, so any tips would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to attach click listener for the whole website. With every click you would ask, if your clicks contains element you want. Don't worry that it will always do if statement for every click, that's really not an performance issue and this is the correct way how to handle this.

The code will look like this (no need to use jQuery). You can check out [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/jafL58mb/1/).

```
const contactSection = document.querySelector('#contact-section');
let isContactSectionShowed = false;

window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target === contactSection && !isContactSectionShowed) {
    contactSection.classList.add("show");
    isContactSectionShowed = true;
  } else if (e.target !== contactSection && isContactSectionShowed) {
    contactSection.classList.remove("show");
    isContactSectionShowed = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const modal = $('#contact-section');

  $("#opencontact").click(function() {
    modal.toggleClass("show");
  });

  $(document).click(function(event) {
    // Check if NOT click on modal or button
    if (!$(event.target).closest("#contact-section, #opencontact").length) {
      modal.removeClass("show")
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#opencontact {
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

#contact-section {
  height: 60%;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

#contact-section.show {
  display: flex;
}

.contact-container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-content {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha256-KzZiKy0DWYsnwMF+X1DvQngQ2/FxF7MF3Ff72XcpuPs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="opencontact" type="button" name="button">
  <i class="far fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
</button>

<section id="contact-section">
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-content">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <label for="">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Message</label>
      <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
      <button type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```